# QGis's Geoferencer plugin isn't able to paste text that has been added to clipboard via mac's "pbcopy" terminal command

Tags: qgis, python, georeferencing, mac, shell

I recently wrote a little script that used mac's `pbcopy` shell command to dump some text into my clipboard for use in the QGis program. For some reason I'm not able to paste stuff that has been `pbcopy`'d into my clipboard into the Geoferencer plugin on qgis. I recently discovered that I *can* paste the text into other elements of the native qgis program, but not the plugin. The text can similarly be pasted into any other program.

I think this has something to do with the way the Georeferencer plugin was written in Python, what with its somewhat unique at times deep bindings into the low levels of the operating system. Maybe some python devs could assist here.

I would save a lot of time in the long run if I could get the georeferencer program to respond to clipboard text that came from the `pbcopy` program.

Comment: Georeferencer GDAL is written in C++

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MaximDubinin But isn't the GUI wrapper written in Python? Its the UI of the function (the "wrapper") that's causing the headache.

Comment: @iant My question is how to work around the fact that running this in the terminal `echo 34.12343 | pbcopy` and trying to paste that coordinate into the georeferencer plugin as a GCP is not possible. Its pretty specific, I know, but if the question belongs anywhere on SE, it belongs here.

Comment: Isn't this really a bug report?

Comment: I see as more of a hurdle, depends on how you look at it

Comment: well I remember we were writing it, including GUI, in C++) In any case, this seems like an issue for https://hub.qgis.org/issues

Comment: Thanks. Luckily the bug report is already done. I'll post it

Comment: Can't delete this question now because there is an answer. Voting to close

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround...

The georeferencer saves GCPs to a simple csv format, here's an example

```
mapX,mapY,pixelX,pixelY,enable
825806.63442017033230513,5422953.92224035412073135,314.35512552301270262,-1134.64180177824141538,1
824769.92792624223511666,5423678.89898734446614981,148.00222280334722313,-377.67625523012361555,1
```

if you can change your script to output to the clipboard in a similar format, you could save that to a file with the 'points' extension and load it in.

Comment: This didn't end up working out because of the necessity for x,y coordinates from the image canvas. I'm just going to pull this question now that I've submitted a bug report to qgis. Thanks though